# Adding legend to barplot

Tags: r, graph

I have a simple barplot:

```
xtabs(~ df$Variable + df$Country)
tab <- xtabs(~ df$Variable + df$Country)
barplot(tab, las=1, yaxp=c(0, 100, 5), ylim=c(0, 100), ylab='Variable', col=c("red","darkblue"))
```

How can I add a legend to the barplot?

Comment: It would help us to answer if you provided data. We cannot run your code without having access to `df`, but it looks like we could run the critical `barplot` line if you simply gave us `tab`.  please use `dput(tab)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Perhaps `barplot(..., legend.text=rownames(tab))`.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot only reports the number of Variable responses collected per Country, and not the levels in the Variable (which is a factor). I've been able to add the legend using the baplot function and adding

```
legend("topright", legend = c("Level 1", "Level 2"), fill = c("red", "darkblue"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `ggplot`. It automatically includes a legend.

```
df <- tibble(
  y = 1:5,
  x = letters[1:5]
)
ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = x))
```

[image]